# Multi Child Processes to read when One parent Process write some string in C language

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I am writing echo server which have 1 parent process, and 3 child processes. The purpose of this server is...

1. Each child process made by the function fork() receives a string from each client.
2. the Parent process should concatenate 3 strings and send every child process.
3. every process have to send the string, concatenated by the parent process, to each client.

I have tried using functions fork, pipe, read, and write.
I made two pipes to communicate between children and parent. Each child process would use write function to pass a string. To receive the string concatenated by parent process, I write source code

After compiling and executing, i have found the logical error that only one client, first executed, receive concatenated string, two rest clients display message "Connection reset by peer".

I closed all pipes after using read and write functions. and i don't know how to manipulate this problem.

How can i make 3 clients can receive the string sent by the server correctly?

I am going to attach the source code.

- Server Code

```c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXLINE 1024
#define PORTNUM 3600

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int p1[2];
    int p2[2];

    pipe(p1);
    pipe(p2);
    int index = 0;
    //char channel[100];
    char full_str[MAXLINE];
    char recv[MAXLINE];
    int isOK1 = 0;
    int isOK2 = 0;

    int listen_fd, client_fd;
    pid_t pid;
    socklen_t addrlen;
    int readn;
    char buf[MAXLINE];
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr, server_addr;

    if( (listen_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    memset((void *)&server_addr, 0x00, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(PORTNUM);

    if(bind(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) ==-1)
    {
        perror("bind error");
        return 1;
    }
    if(listen(listen_fd, 5) == -1)
    {
        perror("listen error");
        return 1;
    }

    signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
    while(1)
    {
        addrlen = sizeof(client_addr);
        client_fd = accept(listen_fd,
            (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &addrlen);
        if(client_fd == -1)
        {
            printf("accept error\n");
            break;
        }
        pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0)
        {
            close( listen_fd );
            close(p1[0]);
            close(p2[1]);
            memset(buf, 0x00, MAXLINE);
            while((readn = read(client_fd, buf, MAXLINE)) > 0)
            {
                printf("Read Data %s(%d) : %s\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), client_addr.sin_port, buf);
                
                write(p1[1], buf, strlen(buf));
                close(p1[1]);
                wait(NULL);

                isOK2 = read(p2[0], recv, MAXLINE);
                
                // When recv read concatenated string by p2 pipe, read function would be executed.
                if(isOK2 > 0){
                    printf("%s I am over\n", recv);
                    write(client_fd, recv, MAXLINE);
                
                    close(p2[0]);
                    exit(1);
                    
                }

                memset(buf, 0x00, MAXLINE);
            }
            close(client_fd);
            return 0;
        }
        else if( pid > 0) {
            close(p1[1]);
            close(p2[0]);

            char channel[100];
            if((isOK1 = read(p1[0], channel, 100)>0)){
                    close(p1[0]);
    
                    strcat(full_str, channel);
                    index++;
                    full_str[strlen(full_str)] = '\0';  
                    printf("%d \n", index); 
                    printf("%s \n", channel);
                    printf("%ld \n", strlen(channel));
                    if(index >= 3) {
                        write(p2[1], full_str, strlen(full_str));
                        close(p2[1]);
                        exit(0);
                    }
                    
                    memset(channel, 0x00, 100);
                
            }
            //wait(NULL);
        }
        close(client_fd);
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

- Client Code

```c
#include <sys/socket.h>  
#include <arpa/inet.h>   
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <string.h>    
#include <unistd.h>     

#define MAXLINE    1024

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
    int server_sockfd;
    int client_len;
    char buf[MAXLINE];

    if ((server_sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) 
    {
        perror("error :");
        return 1;
    }

    server_sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    serveraddr.sin_port = htons(3600);

    client_len = sizeof(serveraddr);

    if (connect(server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, client_len)  == -1)
    {
        perror("connect error :");
        return 1;
    }

    memset(buf, 0x00, MAXLINE);
    read(0, buf, MAXLINE);    
    buf[strlen(buf)-1] = '\0'; // trim text
    if (write(server_sockfd, buf, MAXLINE) <= 0)
    {
        perror("write error : ");
        return 1;
    }
    memset(buf, 0x00, MAXLINE);

    if (read(server_sockfd, buf, MAXLINE) <= 0)
    {
        perror("read error : ");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("read : %s\n", buf);
    close(server_sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use 'pipe' and 'fork' for that.
You mentioned you have 'tried' to use these functions, which could mean, that you thought this would be a good approach, but no, it is not.

You should use 'select' or 'poll', in this way you can handle it in one single thread.

### server

- create server socket, bind and listen
- accept until all clients connected
- do poll/select for read (on client fd's) until all strings are read
- concat strings
- do poll/select for write (on client fd's) until string is written
- close all

### client

- create socket
- connect to server
- do poll/select for read/write until string is written or read
- close socket

If you want multithreading then use threads instead of 'fork'. The reason for that is, that you can share memory between parent and child processes and that eliminates the need of pipes (and additional read and writes).